# convert NSMutableDictionary to JSON and string

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdata, nsmutabledictionary

I want to add a json data to HTTPBody request for an iOS app.
I am using objective c.
So I decided to use `NSMutableDictionary` to convert it to JSON
    @property NSMutableDictionary* project;

Parameters:
     project (required): a hash of the project attributes, including:
     name (required): the project name
     identifier (required): the project identifier
     description
This is the JSON format when adding data as a raw:
If I want the JSON to look like this, do I have to create NSMutableDictionary object and have another NSMutableDictionary object inside it with the key name `@"project"`?

```
{
    "project": {
        "name": "",
        "identifier": "example",
        "description": "",
    }
}
```

I tried to have only one `NSMutableDictionary` 
Here is my code:

```
[self.project setObject:self.projectName.text forKey:@"name"];
[self.project setObject:self.projectDescription.text forKey:@"description"];
[self.project setObject:self.projectIdentifier.text forKey:@"identifier"];
```

Here is how to convert it to JSON:

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:project options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData: data
                                              encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
NSData* anotherdataobj = jsonString;
    [request setHTTPBody:anotherdataobj];
```

I convert it to `NSData` again because `HTTPBody` accept `NSData` for the parameter.

To be clear:
1- do i have to create `NSMutableDictionary` for project and add `NSMutableDictionary` projectdetails as a value for for its key `@"project"`
2- Do I have to convert the string into `NSData` again to pass it for the `HTTPBody`?
Correct me if i'm wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definitely need another dictionary inside the first one. Whether you use a mutable version or a literal is up to you.

Note: you probably want to use the newer and much more readable Objective-C syntax.

Option 1:

```
NSMutableDictionary *object = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *project = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
project[@"name"] = whatever;
project[@"identifier"] = whateverElse;
project[@"description"] = stillSomethingElse;
object[@"project"] = project;
```

Option 2:

```
NSDictionary *object =
@{
    @"project":
    @{
        @"name": whatever,
        @"identifier": whateverElse,
        @"description": stillSomethingElse,
    }
};
```

`NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` already returns an `NSData` object? Why would you need to convert it again? Also, you certainly don't want to cast an `NSData` object to an `NSString`, they're two completely different objects.

Comment: So do you mean that I should just pass the NSData to the setHTTPBody without converting it to NSString with NSUTF8StringEncoding?

Comment: Indeed. Why would you need to convert it, since it's an `NSData` object, and `setHTTPBody` expects an `NSData` object?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!